# Ionic android app works fine on mobile data but failed to send http request on wifi

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework, android-wifi

I am developing app on ionic and angularjs.
Webservices deployed on cloud based server.

My android app is working fine on mobile data but not in wifi.

### App Permissions

```
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="16" android:targetSdkVersion="23" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />
    <permission android:name="${applicationId}.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" android:protectionLevel="signature" />
    <uses-permission android:name="${applicationId}.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

Comment: check from navigator.connection.type that are you getting network info or not .

Comment: And also verify if the port are opened on your wifi. Cordova based permission are normally enough.